# wxPython listctrl flickers with rapid updates

Tags: wxpython, flicker, listctrl

I'm putting some lines in a list control and then updating them fairly quickly - normally the data comes in from a bus - and the whole list flickers quite a lot. It would be really nice to stop it doing that.

I've cut down the code as much as I can while still keeping the general look of what I'm doing in the sample below.

It doesn't seem to matter if the lisctrl is in a wx.Notebook or just a plain wx.Panel so I left the notebook there.

I've started to look at double buffering but wanted to see if there was something else to try first.

Doing this on Windows 7 with wxPython 2.8.12.1. Happens on XP as well though.

```
import sys
import time
import logging
import wx
from random import randint

UPDATE_MS=10

class CanMsg(object):
    def __init__(self, ID, type, len, data=None):
        """Represents a CAN message"""
        self.ID=ID          # 11/29-bit message identifier
        self.MSGTYPE=type # Type of the message
        self.LEN=len          # Data Length Code of the message (0..8)
        if data:
            self.DATA=data
        else:
            self.DATA=[0,]*len

class EmulatorFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title, pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.DefaultSize, 
                                style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, pos, size, style)
        # create frame menu and status bar
        self.status = self.CreateStatusBar()
        # create tab panels
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        nb = wx.Notebook(panel)
        self.messages_tab = MessagesTab(nb)
        # self.messages_tab = MessagesTab(panel)
        # add tab pages to notebook
        nb.AddPage(self.messages_tab, 'CAN data')
        self._nb = nb

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(nb, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        # sizer.Add(self.messages_tab, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        minSize=self.ClientToWindowSize(sizer.GetMinSize())     # get this as Info tab's min size is too small
        panel.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        self.SetInitialSize(minSize)

        self.InitialiseTimers()

    def InitialiseTimers(self):
        # tab updates and test comparison timer
        self.displayTimer=wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnRefresh, self.displayTimer)
        self.displayTimer.Start(UPDATE_MS)
        # self.Bind(wx.EVT_IDLE, self.OnRefresh)

    def OnRefresh(self, event):
        self.messages_tab.Update(can_send, can_recv)

class MessagesTab(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        msg_size=450    # width of messge windows
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY)

        receivedLabel=wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, 'Messages Received')
        receivedLabel.SetForegroundColour('blue')
        sentLabel=wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, 'Messages Sent')
        sentLabel.SetForegroundColour('dark slate blue')
        SentMsgList = MessageList(self, size=wx.Size(msg_size,150))
        ReceivedMsgList = MessageList(self, size=wx.Size(msg_size,150))

        sizer=wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(sentLabel, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 2)
        sizer.Add(SentMsgList, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 2)
        sizer.Add(receivedLabel, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 2)
        sizer.Add(ReceivedMsgList, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 2)

        b = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, 'Clear messages', name='clear_stale')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClearMessages, b)
        sizer.Add(b, proportion=0, flag=wx.ALL, border=4)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.SentMsgList = SentMsgList
        self.ReceivedMsgList = ReceivedMsgList

    def Update(self, can_send, can_recv):
        self.SentMsgList.Populate(can_send)
        self.ReceivedMsgList.Populate(can_recv)

    def OnClearMessages(self, event):
        self.SentMsgList.DeleteAllItems()
        self.ReceivedMsgList.DeleteAllItems()

class MessageList(wx.ListCtrl):
    def __init__(self, parent, ID=wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                        size=wx.DefaultSize, style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.LC_HRULES|wx.LC_VRULES|wx.LC_SORT_ASCENDING):
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, ID, pos, size, style)
        self.InsertColumn(0, "COB-ID")
        self.InsertColumn(1, "Type")
        self.InsertColumn(2, "Len")
        self.InsertColumn(3, "Data")
        self.InsertColumn(4, "Cycle [ms]")
        self.SetColumnWidth(0, 60)
        self.SetColumnWidth(1, 40)
        self.SetColumnWidth(2, 40)
        self.SetColumnWidth(3, 200)
        self.SetColumnWidth(4, 75)

    # either add messages to the listctrl or update the existing ones if 
    def Populate(self, msg_store):
        item=-1
        while 1:
            item = self.GetNextItem(item, wx.LIST_NEXT_ALL, wx.LIST_STATE_DONTCARE)
            if item == -1: break
            if self.GetItemText(item) not in msg_store:
                self.DeleteItem(item)

        for msg_id in msg_store:
            item = self.FindItem(-1, msg_id)
            msg = msg_store.get(msg_id)
            interval = randint(10,1000)
            # insert new messages
            if item == -1:
                item = self.InsertStringItem(sys.maxint, msg_id)
                self.SetStringItem(item, 1, 'std')
            # fill in other columns
            self.SetStringItem(item, 2, '%1d'%msg.LEN)
            self.SetStringItem(item, 3, ' '.join(['%02x'%d for d in msg.DATA[:msg.LEN]]))
            self.SetStringItem(item, 4, '%d'%interval)
#====================================================================
#====================================================================
if __name__=='__main__':
    msg=(0x180, 0, 8, range(1,9))
    can_send={}
    can_recv={}
    # just make up some simple messages for listctrl to display
    # send msgs
    for a in range(1,7):
        this_msg=list(msg)
        this_msg[0] += a
        can_send[hex(this_msg[0])] = CanMsg(*msg)
    # receive msgs
    for a in range(1,10):
        this_msg=list(msg)
        this_msg[0] += 0x100+a
        can_recv[hex(this_msg[0])] = CanMsg(*msg)

    app=wx.App(0)   # 0 arg stops stdout/stderr text box pop-up, messages go to console
    frame = EmulatorFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, 'Listctrl flicker test')
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I think I finally have a workable (if partial) answer the flicker problem.

I found a number of people had success, mostly with image flickering, by enabling double buffering on the panel.
So in the MessagesTab() class, after the wx.Panel init, I inserted the line;

```
self.SetDoubleBuffered(True)
```

This made the list control updates smooth but resizing the GUI or mousing over the listctrl column headers would make the contents flicker a lot or disappear entirely. Being Windows 7 the header highlights as per the OS theme when the mouse is on it. Since this seemed to be the cause my workaround was to add the wx.LC_NO_HEADER flag to the MessageList() style arg. So the listctrl has no header but nothing causes flicker or vanishing text now and I can replace it with some static text. Resizing is no problem either.

So maybe there's some problem with events generated on the column headers?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using wxPython's Freeze and Thaw methods. Basically you Freeze the widget, update it and then you Thaw it.

Comment: I have tried freeze/thaw in a couple of places, including the beginning/end of MessagesTab's Update method and EmulatorFrame's OnRefresh method. They never seem to have any effect (on Windows) which appears to be what other people have found. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: The only other answer I found was back in 2008 where it was suggested to use the ListCtrl's virtual mode: http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/Screen-flicker-while-updating-a-ListCtrl-td2362816.html